# Cannot move std::unique_ptr with NULL deleter to std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++14, move, unique-ptr

I want to move a NULL *std::unique_ptr* to a *std::shared_ptr*, like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<float> test = nullptr;
std::shared_ptr<float> test2 = std::move(test);
```

As far as I know it should be legal to do so, and it does run fine in Visual Studio 2015 and GCC.

However, I can't do the same with a *std::unique_ptr* which has a deleter declaration, like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<float,void(*)(float*)> test = nullptr;
std::shared_ptr<float> test2 = std::move(test);
```

The code above will not compile in visual studio and will trigger the static assert failure "error C2338: unique_ptr constructed with null deleter pointer".

I can use a *std::function* deleter instead, in which case the static assert failure can be circumvented:

```
std::unique_ptr<float,std::function<void(float*)>> test = nullptr;
std::shared_ptr<float> test2 = std::move(test);
```

In this case the code compiles fine, but I get an abort as soon as the last *std::shared_ptr* copy of *test2* is destroyed.

Why are the latter two cases so problematic?

Strangely enough, if I change the type of *test2* from *std::shared_ptr* to *std::unique_ptr*, the second case still triggers the static assert failure, but both case 1 and case 3 work just fine:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<float> test = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<float> test2 = std::move(test); // Works fine
}
{
    //std::unique_ptr<float,void(*)(float*)> test = nullptr; // triggers a static assert failure
    //std::unique_ptr<float,void(*)(float*)> test2 = std::move(test);
}
{
    std::unique_ptr<float,std::function<void(float*)>> test = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<float,std::function<void(float*)>> test2 = std::move(test); // Works fine
}
```

Comment: None of this makes sense to me, because constructing a `shared_ptr` using a moved `unique_ptr` that has a null object pointer is the same as default constructing the `shared_ptr`, ie it still holds a null object pointer. So what if the deleter is also null? What you are really trying to accomplish by constructing a null `shared_ptr` from a null `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unique_ptr` constructor you are trying to use, which default-constructs the deleter, is ill-formed (before C++17) or disabled by SFINAE (as of C++17) if the deleter type is a pointer, in order to stop you from accidentally creating a `unique_ptr` whose deleter is itself a null pointer. If you really want to create such a `unique_ptr`, you can do so by explicitly passing a null deleter:

```
std::unique_ptr<float,void(*)(float*)> test(nullptr, nullptr);
```

This `unique_ptr` object is not very useful, because it can't delete anything.

By using a null `std::function` deleter, you've told the compiler "yes, I really want to shoot myself in the foot". Of course, when the last `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed, the null `std::function` is invoked, and undefined behaviour occurs. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo Brian's answer and add that in situations like this where the function shouldn't be null, you can use a function *reference,* which are nonnullable like all C++ references, instead of function pointers.

```
void delete_float(float *f) {delete f;}

using Deleter = void(float*);

// Function pointers
constexpr void(*fptr)(float*) = delete_float;
constexpr Deleter *fptr_typedef = delete_float;
constexpr auto fptr_auto = delete_float;
constexpr auto *fptr_auto2 = delete_float;

// Function references
constexpr void(&fref)(float*) = delete_float;
constexpr Deleter &fref_typedef = delete_float;
constexpr auto &fref_auto = delete_float;
```

The one gotcha you need to keep in mind with function references is that lambdas implicitly convert to function pointers, but not function references, so you need to use the dereference operator `*` to convert a lambda to a function reference.

```
const Deleter *fptr_lambda = [](float *f) {delete f;};
// const Deleter &fref_lambda = [](float *f) {delete f;}; // error
const Deleter &fref_lambda_fixed = *[](float *f) {delete f;};
```